# How to install Tiqwah package

Tags: fonts, hebrew

I've been trying to typeset a document in Biblical Hebrew, and ran into [this document](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb15-3/tb44haralambous-hebrew.pdf) describing the Tiqwah LaTeX package. However, after trying tlmgr unsuccessfully, I have not been able to find out how to download the package, and was wondering if anyone could help me with this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks that's quite old package and isn't included at ctan.org. If I were you, I would check out some proper fonts with Hebrew and use xelatex, lualatex or context. A tip for further explorations: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85251/xetex-and-luatex-fail-to-display-correctly-biblical-hebrew-fonts

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Originally (1991?) it was not free being part of ScholarTeX.  [This page](http://tex.loria.fr/english/distributions.html) suggests that it is now obselete.  Trying looking on CTAN for other hebrew packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you can use XeTeX together with the [culmus](http://culmus.sourceforge.net/) fonts. You can see a working example, together with cantilation marks for Biblical Hebrew in [here](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2015/03/20/hebrew-with-xetex-example/). You can also easily use the [Taamy Culmus](http://culmus.sourceforge.net/taamim/index.html) fonts, which look more promising for that purpose but I haven't had real experience with them.